# Can anyone advise how to further debug this HttpClient injection error (No provider for http_HttpClient) in an AngularJS/Angular hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, code-injection

So I have a hybrid AngularJS/Angular app which is all working fine apart from I cannot get the HttpClient module to inject (No provider for http_HttpClient). Strangely enough the deprecated @angular/http module works fine.

So how this works is we start with an AngularJS app, then load up Angular and related modules, and configure it using ngUpgrade to get Angular to boot the AngularJS app. You can then use Angular components in the AngularJS app, and upgrade the AngularJS components over time.

So got this all working after lots of trial and error, apart from the HttpClient module.

This is the main app.ts which defines and boostraps the AngularJS app and the Angular app (note the deprecated @angular/http module is only being used as a test. The one I really need is @angular/common/http):

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import * as angular from "angular";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent, downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// Angular Components
import { FeedbackComponent } from '../app/angular/main/dashboard/dashboardpanel/panels/feedback/feedback.component';
import { UserFeedbackComponent } from './angular/main/help/user-feedback/user-feedback.component';
import { NotificationModalComponent } from './angular/shared/notifications/notificationmodal/notification-modal.component';
import { NotificationSnackbarService } from './angular/shared/notifications/notificationsnackbar/notification-snackbar.service';
import { DashboardPanelComponent } from './angular/main/dashboard/dashboardpanel/dashboardpanel.component';


//Angular services
import { FeedbackService } from './angular/main/dashboard/dashboardpanel/panels/feedback/feedback.service';
import { FeedbackService } from './angular/main/dashboard/dashboardpanel/panels/feedback/feedback.service';

// The AngularJS app
const angularjsApp = angular
  .module('angularjsApp', [])
  .factory('feedbackService', downgradeInjectable(FeedbackService))
  .factory('userFeedbackService', downgradeInjectable(UserFeedbackService))
  // Downgrade the Angular Components
  .directive(
    'angularDashboardPanel',
    downgradeComponent({component: DashboardPanelComponent})//as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  )
  .directive(
    'angularFeedbackComponent',
    downgradeComponent({component: FeedbackComponent})//as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );

// Angular app
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardPanelComponent,
    FeedbackComponent,
    UserFeedbackComponent,
    NotificationModalComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DashboardPanelComponent,
    FeedbackComponent,
    UserFeedbackComponent,
    NotificationModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
 providers: [
    FeedbackService,
    UserFeedbackService,
    NotificationSnackbarService,
  ],
})

export class AppModule {
   //Override Angular bootstrap so it doesn't do anything
   ngDoBootstrap() {
  }

  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

// Bootstrap using the UpgradeModule
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  console.log("Bootstrapping in Hybrid mode with Angular & AngularJS");
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['angularjsApp'], {strictDi: true});
});

export default angularjsApp;
```

The service (UserFeedbackService) where I attempt to inject HttpClient (note that if I try to inject it in a component I get the same error, so it does not look like it is anything to do with the service):

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Http, Response, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class UserFeedbackService {
    constructor(private http: Http,
              private httpClient: HttpClient, // This line causes the error
              private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
              private dialog: MatDialog) {}

}
```

Here is the error:

```
UserFeedbackComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:5 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[UserFeedbackComponent -> UserFeedbackService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserFeedbackService -> http_HttpClient]: 
    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserFeedbackService -> http_HttpClient]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for http_HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:11564:27)
    at resolveToken (core.js:12300:24)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:12245:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:12140:20)
    at resolveToken (core.js:12300:24)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:12245:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:12140:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:24401:29)
    at _createClass (core.js:24456:32)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:24420:26)
View_UserFeedbackComponent_Host_0 @ UserFeedbackComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:5
proxyClass @ compiler.js:25336
logError @ core.js:33167
handleError @ core.js:6990
dispatchEvent @ core.js:24026
eval @ core.js:31370
eval @ platform-browser.js:607
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:447
onInvokeTask @ core.js:29112
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:446
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:218
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:529
invokeTask @ zone.js:1718
globalCallback @ zone.js:1749
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1785

ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_UserFeedbackComponent_Host_0   @   UserFeedbackComponen…Host.ngfactory.js:5
proxyClass  @   compiler.js:25336
logError    @   core.js:33167
handleError @   core.js:6995
dispatchEvent   @   core.js:24026
eval    @   core.js:31370
eval    @   platform-browser.js:607
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:447
onInvokeTask    @   core.js:29112
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:446
Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:218
ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:529
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1718
globalCallback  @   zone.js:1749
globalZoneAwareCallback @   zone.js:1785
```

This is the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/elements": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "12.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/service-worker": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^12.2.16",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.7.2",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.2",
    "@nrwl/angular": "12.9.0",
    "@types/angular": "^1.8.4",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
     ...
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.6",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0"
    ...
}
```

ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.6
Node: 14.18.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, core, elements, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
... service-worker, upgrade

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1202.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular      12.2.6
@angular-devkit/core               12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics         12.2.17
@angular/cdk                       12.2.13
@angular/cli                       12.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli              12.2.0
@angular/http                      7.2.16
@angular/language-service          12.2.0
@angular/material                  12.2.13
@angular/material-moment-adapter   13.3.9
@schematics/angular                12.2.17
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.7.4
webpack                            4.46.0
```

Other providers inject OK, so looks only to be an issue with the HttpClient.

Note also that I have scaffolded a basic AngularJS and Angular app as a test using the same Angular version 12*, and used ngUpgrade to bootstrap it, and injected HttpClient with no issues.

The app with the error above is a much larger production app. How to proceed?

I have logged a case with Angular support but they say use stackoverflow!

So, I have spent a while trying to find a solution to this, so any help going forward will be appreciated!

Comment: Also, if anyone has positive experiences using alternative upgrade methods it would be welcomed.

Comment: Is it possible to create a simple repo in github to reproduce it?

Comment: Not really - the app is too large. I have scaffolded a very small angularJS/Angular app using ngUpgrade and that does not have the problem injecting HttPClient.

Comment: So, you answered your question: start reducing the size of your codebase and you will find out the root cause

Answer (score 0):

Import the HttpClientModule `@angular/common/http` in the root app.module.ts

Add it to the imports array inside the ngModule of root app.module.ts.

```
@ngModule {
.
.
imports : [HttpClientModule]
.
.
}
```

This should let angular inject the HttpClient object to every other components.

Comment: It is in the root module. My root module is called app.ts at the moment. All other imports work.